# Getting href value via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the value of `href` and `hash` of an `a` tag. When I do

```
$(document.body).on('click',"a",function(event){ 
    console.log($(this));
});
```

I see an object with something like

```
[a.internalLink, context: a.internalLink, jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
    0: a.internalLink
        accessKey: ""
        attributes: NamedNodeMap
        ...
        hash: "#abc.1.2"
        ...
        href: "http://www.example.com/page.html#abc.1.2
        ...
```

But when I tried to get the value by `console.log($(this).href)`, it just doesn't work (prints out "undefined"). How can I get it?

Comment: just do `this.href` or `$(this).attr('href')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to refer to specific attributes of an element, you can use the `attr` function of jQuery:

```
$(document.body).on('click',"a",function(event){ 
    console.log( $(this).attr("href") );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$( "a" )[0].href` or `$( "a" ).attr( "href" )`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function () { 
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document.body).on('click',"a",function(event){ 
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code clicking "a" tag will give list of all the anchor tag objects in your page in an array for `$(this)`. And each of these objects have jQuery specific properties (as *this* wrapped in jQuery) like href, hash etc.

So if you have only one anchor tag then you can use `$(this)[0].href`

But the more specific solution will be to use `$(this).attr("href")`

Answer (score 0):

You can get both: full href or just the hash using this code:

```
$("body").on("click","a",function() {
  var href = $(this).attr("href")
  var hash = href.replace(/^.*?#/,'');
  console.log(href + " - " + hash);
});
```

you can see a [demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsCPP/).